# Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin triggering jobs for all branches/projects during indexing

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-cloud

We've recently started using the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin in our Jenkins CI to group our jobs into a single Bitbucket Team Project instead of having multiple standalone multi-branch pipeline jobs.
However, whenever branch indexing occurs it triggers a build for every single branch the repos have instead of just the branches which have changes.

Am I doing something very stupid in the configuration?

Details:

1. Bitbucket Cloud
2. Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin version: 2.2.14
3. Jenkins version: 2.121.3

---

EDIT:

I tried to upload screenshots the first time but it's complaining about formatting. I just left the screenshot links below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUt3r.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLWla.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLVfl.png

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually an underlying authentication issue with the bitbucket authentication I was using to poll Bitbucket from Jenkins.

If anyone has a similar issue, try setting up an app password for you bitbucket user and using those credentials to poll bitbucket from Jenkins instead